# Disabling WHMCS Billing

Tags: whm, cron

I am currently taking over a business which is using WHMCS and CPANEL for hosting and I don't want to use this solution.   The migration away from this system is going to take a while due to the complexities of the migration.

It appears that WHMCS has some useful automated jobs (mainly updating SSL Certificates), but is also doing periodic billing which I want to stop.

The version of WHMCS is v5.2.3 (Yes....)

**Does anyone know how I can kill whatever it is that is scheduling and sending invoices?***   (I assume its some cron job, but I have been unable to find sufficient information to identify what all the various cronjobs do, and nothing stands out).   I'm very comfortable working at the command line and have root access if it makes any difference.

Comment: WHMCS doesn't update autoSSL, that is done by WHM.

Comment: @Steve - and here is me not knowing the differnece between WHMCS and WHM!  I thought they were the same thing.  Doh.

Comment: Do you understand it now?  For future readers:  WHM (Web Host Manager) is part of cPanel and is the administration interface for server settings.  WHMCS is software that is part of the cPanel empire, it is designed for web hosting business operators and manages user accounts including invoicing, creating cPanel accounts and much more.  It is very closely tied to cPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved this.  In WHMCS I went to Setup -> Automation Settings.
The top of this page describes the cron job you need to create for billing.
(It has the rather oblique name cron.php in the appropriate directory for the setup).

I then went to the user who owned the WHMCS website and commented out the offending line.